# Is sprockets caching views/erb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am deploying all my assets on s3, and pre-compiling them on deployment. In theory sprockets shouldn't really do anything during runtime.

However, when I debug my cache I keep seeing some sprockets activity: 
cache miss: sprockets/dbc38e827b53b65e2f3840f004685b57 (0.7ms)
cache hit: sprockets/bd37d101b41cff7ff25f3a3492a8cd6e (0.1ms)

Any ideas?

Is it possible that rails uses sprockets to resolve the asset path, and every time a new path gets resolved it caches it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you disable the asset pipeline in your production environment. Inside your `production.rb`:

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to asset pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false
```

Check out the example `production.rb` in [Rails Asset Pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#upgrading-from-old-versions-of-rails).